# Microsoft Graph API - 401 Unauthorized While Creating Chat

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph-api, chat, http-status-code-401

I using the graph API v1.0 to create the one-to-One chat,but I found some account get 401 results.I check the Permission from the Api '/me/oauth2PermissionGrants',and I can find the 'Chat.Create' permission.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#oauth2PermissionGrants",
    "value": [
        {
            "clientId": "9fc4855b-4d7e-443b-a8f0-282690a55a73",
            "consentType": "Principal",
            "id": "W4XEn35NO0So8CgmkKVacwsSh1fUKDpBhq1AxEmfwg74z92MWfk9ToJPj-kyp8I8",
            "principalId": "8cddcff8-f959-4e3d-824f-8fe932a7c23c",
            "resourceId": "5787120b-28d4-413a-86ad-40c4499fc20e",
            "scope": " offline_access openid profile email User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Chat.ReadWrite Chat.Create Presence.Read Presence.Read.All ChatMessage.Read ChatMessage.Send"
        },
        {
            "clientId": "d39356e1-6d20-4d19-ad54-5278e19b94ec",
            "consentType": "Principal",
            "id": "4VaT0yBtGU2tVFJ44ZuU7AsSh1fUKDpBhq1AxEmfwg74z92MWfk9ToJPj-kyp8I8",
            "principalId": "8cddcff8-f959-4e3d-824f-8fe932a7c23c",
            "resourceId": "5787120b-28d4-413a-86ad-40c4499fc20e",
            "scope": " offline_access openid profile email User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Chat.ReadWrite Chat.Create Presence.Read Presence.Read.All ChatMessage.Read ChatMessage.Send"
        },
        {
            "clientId": "c81831d1-608e-43fa-abd4-3a09e523cb3c",
            "consentType": "Principal",
            "id": "0TEYyI5g-kOr1DoJ5SPLPAsSh1fUKDpBhq1AxEmfwg74z92MWfk9ToJPj-kyp8I8",
            "principalId": "8cddcff8-f959-4e3d-824f-8fe932a7c23c",
            "resourceId": "5787120b-28d4-413a-86ad-40c4499fc20e",
            "scope": " offline_access openid profile email User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Chat.ReadWrite Chat.Create Presence.Read Presence.Read.All ChatMessage.Read ChatMessage.Send Files.Read Files.ReadWrite Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I post "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats",
set the body like this

```
{"members":[
        {   "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('8cddcff8-f959-4e3d-824f-8fe932a7c23c')",
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles":["owner"]},
        {   "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('636f150e-f73c-44d6-be0c-4d543b2b4e5d')",
            "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "roles":["owner"]
        }
    ],
    "chatType":"oneOnOne"
}
```

It response 401 Authentication failed

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "message": "Authentication failed.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-05-17T08:41:05",
            "request-id": "de03512e-b97d-4229-b1ce-a73a61ed4f3d",
            "client-request-id": "de03512e-b97d-4229-b1ce-a73a61ed4f3d"
        }
    }
}
```

When I replace another account's token & teamsUserId and try again ,It returns Ok!
Can you help me check the reason?

Comment: Please check if the token getting 401 has permission Chat.Create or Chat.ReadWrite by putting the token in https://jwt.ms

Comment: Thanks for your reply！I tried according to your suggestion,and I got the "scp": "Chat.Create Chat.ReadWrite ChatMessage.Read ChatMessage.Send email Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All openid Presence.Read Presence.Read.All profile Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite"

Comment: What is the type of account you are using? Is it work or school account or personal?

Comment: How can I get the information about this? I'm not sure about this

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Generally speaking, our accounts are all company accounts,we got it from company.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check your app id secret and confirm
secondly check that the users you are trying to add have authorized your application.
thirdly check for access token you need scopes and permission according to the token you are sending to the graph
If you are using application token , use default scope and check whether you have added the chat.create application permission else if you are using token on behalf of user you need delegated permission for chat.create application

Comment: I am sure this account token has permission about chat.create, I can see it in decrypted token.    Last night,I stopped refreshing token ,and get a new token from graph again today, then it be ok now! I can not understand how it happend. Maybe I should check all work account, try to resolve this trouble